# Git push Unable to create master.lock': Permission denied

Tags: git, svn

I am unable to push as user svn.

```
cd admin
git push stash --all
fatal: Unable to create '/home/svn/gitrepos/admin/refs/remotes/stash/master.lock': Permission denied
Unexpected end of command stream
```

It does allow me to push as root though:

```
sudo git push stash --all                                                                                  
[sudo] password for svn:
Username:
Password:
Everything up-to-date
```

I did not have this problem before, is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Why is SVN involved? Are you using a git-to-svn bridge/plugin?

Comment: `svn` is the user. But yes, this repository happens to be created by svn2git tool.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the `/home/svn/gitrepos/admin/refs/stash` group has write permission?  Also, SVN user must be in the group.